# firebase orderby key vs orderby timestamp, for pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data looks something like this in my firebase.

```
users: {
-KOwKNCB5IiDBxY9FNzR: {
  content: { blah blah },
  timestamp:1470964762934

 },
 -KOwKNCB5IiDBxYsdsds: {
   content: { blah blah },
   timestamp:1444964762934
 },
 --HHiOwKNCB5IiDBxY9FN: {
   content: { blah blah },
   timestamp:1579864762934
 }
}
```

What is difference between these two?

- `....orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(starttime).endAt(endTime).limitToLast(10)`
- `....orderByKey().startAt(starttime).endAt(endTime).limitToLast(10)`

I used push ref key when I added the data. Firebase uses timestamp based key, right? In that case, what is the difference between the two below? Both will give the same result? How about performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent; the key-based query in your example will not work.

The Firebase key is derived from the timestamp, but it is more than a simple milliseconds count. To perform a temporal query against keys, you will need to convert your timestamps to keys. There is a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11) that demonstrates the algorithm.

If you convert the timestamps in your key-based query to actual keys, the two queries should be equivalent within reason - the timestamp used by Firebase to generate the keys for the pushed data might not match the `timestamp` that you have stored in the data.

However, for performance reasons, you would need to [put an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) on the `timestamp` property. With an index in place, you'd need to do some testing to determine whether there is a significant performance advantage in using the key-based query.

Comment: Something to be aware of is that Firebase takes clock offsets into account. When generating keys, after the first call in which Firebase communicates with the server, Firebase will take into consideration the clock offset between the local machine and the Firebase servers.